# Getting MVC default route to go to ~/default.asp

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I am adding some MVC features to an existing site (FWIW, most of which is in classic ASP). As a result, I need to keep the default routing going to ~/default.asp  (at a minimum - preferably the default document specified in IIS).

Is there a way to write the route in RegisterRoutes so that a request for the root of the site (e.g., http://localhost, http://localhost/, or http://localhost/default.asp) will directly get the default page, and not attempt to find a controller/action?  Or do I need to write my own HttpModule that will filter it and keep it from getting to the MvcHandler (as in [this blog](http://blog.davidwalker.org/2008/08/aspnet-mvc-and-the-default-route/))?

BTW, I have googled this, but most of the hits are for MVC version 1 or older, and default routing appears to have changed in version 2 (i.e, there is no more default.aspx that redirects to ~/Home), so they are not directly applicable. Even so, the ones that were there didn't address this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maarten Balliauw has written a nice artice about [mixing ASP.NET Webforms and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc). The thing you need from the article is the part where you tell MVC not to route certain routes:

In your case this would be:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("default.asp/{*pathInfo}"); // If you don't pass arguments just use default.asp
routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

After these ignores, provide your regular MVC routes. This way MVC will ignore these routes and will let Webforms handle them. Provided that `/` will point to `/default.asp` in Webforms, this should work. However, I haven't tested this...

Comment: I hadn't thought of "IgnoreRoute("")". Thansk